# When I retrieve a non-indexed column from a large table, SQL Server looks up the PK

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a huge table which has millions of rows:

```
create table BigTable
(
    id bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    value float not null,
    vid char(1) NOT NULL,
    dnf char(4) NOT NULL,
    rbm char(6) NOT NULL,
    cnt char(2) not null,
    prs char(1) not null,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
)
```

There is a non-clustered unique index on this table which is on the following columns:

```
vid, dnf, rbm, cnt, prs
```

Now I would like to get some data out of this huge table with a partial index:

```
insert into #t
    select b.id, b.rbm, b.value
    from 
        (select distinct x from #t1) a
    join 
        BigTable b on b.vid = '1'
                   and b.dnf = '1234'
                   and b.rbm = a.x
```

where:

```
create table #t
(
    id  integer primary key,
    rbm varchar(8),
    val float null
)

create index tmp_idx_t on #t(rbm)

create table #t1 (rbm char(6) not null)
```

If I don't include the `value` column in the query, the execution plan will not show the PK lookup on `BigTable`. But if I have the `value` in the resultset, a PK lookup will be on `BigTable`. The output list of this lookup is the very column `val`.

But I am not using any PKs here so it takes a lot of time to finish. Is there a way to stop that PK lookup? Or am I writing wrong SQL?

I know the `BigTable` is not a great design but I can't change it.

Answer (score 3):

In order to avoid the PK index lookup you'll need to include all the columns (filtering predicate AND result set) in the index. For example:

```
create index ix1 on BigTable (dnf, vid, rbm) include (value);
```

This index only uses the first three columns (dnf, vid, rbm) for search, and adds (value) columns as data. As pointed out by @DanGusman the `id` column is always present in a SQL Server secondary index. This way the index has all the data it needs to resolve the query.

Alternatively, you could use the old way:

```
create index ix1 on BigTable (dnf, vid, rbm, value);
```

This will also work, but will generate a heavier index. That being said, this heavier index may also be of use for other queries.

Comment: The `id` column clustered index key is implicitly included in all non-clustered index so including only `value` will cover the query.

Comment: This looks nice. But it might be impossible for me to create indices on the big table. But anyway thank you.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks for pointing this out. I always forget in SQL Server all indexes (safe the PK) are "secondary indexes", and they must include the pk.

Comment: @DanGuzman It's been years since I look at the b-tree structures but I don't believe that's correct. As with any index a clustered index can contain multiple key columns. The nonclustered indexes reference the clustered index by RID (Row ID) and still have to do an index Seek on the clustered index to lookup the actual ID column value to return in the select statement.

Comment: @DanGuzman I apologize, I'm obviously mis-remembering. When `create index ix1 on BigTable (dnf, vid, rbm) include (value)` is used as a covering index `SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON` does not show an index seek on the clustered index so it must be including the ID column value in it instead of an RID.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I was reading your comment, and never heard of a "row ID" in SQL Server. Do those exist? As far as I remember SQL Server does not use the heap model (as well as MySQL, Sybase, MariaDB).

Comment: @TheImpaler It's possible they're no longer used in current SQL Server implementations. Here's an example from 2007, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2007/06/07/what-happens-to-non-clustered-indexes-when-the-table-structure-is-changed/

Comment: @AlwaysLearning You are right. SQL Server does currently support the heap model with tables defined as "non clustered". I have rarely seen one for ages now; pretty much all of them are clustered (default organization) nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Your index is lacking the `id` column.  In order to resolve the query, the engine needs to go to the data pages.  I would advise you include the column in the index, so the index covers the query.

I am thinking that you might try writing the query as:

```
select b.id, b.rbm, b.value
from BigTable b
where b.vid = '1' and
      b.dnf = '1234' and
      exists (select 1 from #t1 t1 where t1.x = b.rbm);
```

This might encourage SQL Server to use a more optimal execution plan, even when `id` is not in the index.

Comment: Thanks for your code but it looks like it doesn't even use the partial index.

Comment: It couldn't possibly finish so I killed it.